# Combining categorical data with numeric data when using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have to following data (3 million rows):

```
user_id | datetime   | type
1       | 2015-01-01 | q
1       | 2015-01-01 | d
1       | 2015-01-02 | d
2       | 2015-01-01 | d
2       | 2015-01-02 | q
2       | 2015-01-02 | q
```

I want to obtain the following dataframe:

```
user_id | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02 
1       | q:1, d:1   | d:1 
2       | d:1        | q:2
```

I know that I could use `pivot_table` if there was not the `type` column. However, I also need to consider it. I wonder if anyone has any elegant solution to this problem?

P.S. The output table cells do not have too look exactly the same. As an alternative solution, the counts (of d and q) could be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`to_json`***
This gets you really close.  The cell values are strings.

```
df.groupby(
    ['user_id', 'datetime']
).type.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).to_json()).unstack()
```

[image]

***`MultiIndex`***
This may make more sense

```
df.groupby(
    ['user_id', 'datetime']).type.apply(pd.value_counts).unstack(['datetime', -1])
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, I have a quick question, what if 'type' field has values of 1 and 2 instead of q and d, and if I wanted to put in the cells: 1 (if only a `q`), 2 (if only a `d`), 3 (if both)? Thanks again...

Comment: @renakre I just tried it.  It worked just fine.  However, the `json` version produces strings for the keys instead of integers.